# Google Drive sync on Juno

Tags: release-juno

I just installed Juno 5.0 x64 and I was wondering how to sync my Google Drive on my laptop.

I've tried some methods but there was no success. :(
 I've searched here for this question, but they were for older versions.

Please help me I am so a beginner in Linux I am so desperate :D

Thank you!

Comment: PS: I found solutions for/on GNOME --> but this aren't compatible for me I think (ex. when I try to open from the Terminal the GNOME Control Center it is blank and I cant do anything in it!)

Answer (score 1):

I also tried some "scripting solutions" but finally I came to [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/). It's not free but in my opinion it's worth its prize. 
Maybe you will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Overgrive, also not fee, but it's only $5 and it works really well- https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive

Answer (score 0):

solution 
Google Drive GUI for Windows / Mac / Linux

https://liberodark.github.io/ODrive/

Answer (score 0):

Try `grive2`. https://github.com/vitalif/grive2

It is command line but easy to use. there is a quick howto on installing and using it on Ubuntu based distros like elementary at this link:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-sync-your-google-cloud-on-linux-with-grive2/.

I have it working on my Elementary Os Juno [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno) desktop right now.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by Milos you can use

https://liberodark.github.io/ODrive/

The only problem I found was with the indicator in the wingpanel. You can resotre it following this guide:
https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators

Juno doesn't support anymore 3rd party application indicator as described in this closed issue:
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues/96

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I used

```
apt-get install install gnome-shell`
```

(Backup your `/home` and or don't do this on a machine you really need. This might bork your install.)

---

- I had to use fix install `sudo apt-get install -f`, because of the dependencies.
- Choose gdm over lightdm when prompted using your up and down arrow keys and enter.
- On reboot chose gnome or Ubuntu gnome and setup Google in Accounts under Settings.
- Open Applications, then gnome files and then get your google drive.
- Open Applications, then elementary files make sure it is there too.
- Reboot, and thereafter always use Pantheon at the gdm login and files will have your drive.

---

It is ugly. You may get `apt-get update` complaining that `/etc/apt/sources.list` has everything configured multiple times.

(You can probably delete the `*.saved` files? Comment out universe and/or multiverse lines with a `#`?) But on the bright side you will have all of the gnome apps after adding `Gnome-` plus your Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have found OverGrive works the best and it is only about $5.